# Why is mediatomb not compiled with javascript support?

Tags: 11.04, package-management, mediaserver, upnp

I've been using mediatomb for a while and when I've decided to present files and folders in a custom way, I figured out that mediatomb in ubuntu 11.4 (server) was not compiled with javascript.

Has anyone encountered this situation, and find a "simple" (few steps) solution ?

note I tried to compile & repack mediatomb, but one of its dependency libjs is now libmozjs185 API & ABI changed so I aborted.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediatomb is not compiled with javascript because the repository libraries (*libmozjs185*) does not support the compilation of SpiderMonkey into MediaTomb.

Looking back - this particular build-receipe has been used since v10.04 (lucid) thus you'll need to repack the Debian MediaTomb packages with Javascript support yourself.

**Prereqs for repacking with javascript support**

You'll need to "borrow" some older libraries from Debian Sid - and remove the offending libraries if you have them installed i.e.

get libmozjs2d and libmozjs-dev from the debian sid distibution: [libmozjs2d_1.9.1.16-6_i386.deb](http://pkgs.org/debian-sid/debian-main-i386/libmozjs2d_1.9.1.16-6_i386.deb.html) and [libmozjs-dev_1.9.1.16-6_i386.deb](http://pkgs.org/debian-sid/debian-main-i386/libmozjs-dev_1.9.1.16-6_i386.deb.html)
& install a missing library

```
sudo apt-get remove libmozjs185*
sudo apt-get install build-essential libnspr4-0d 
sudo dpkg -i libmoz*.deb
```

**Obtain the source**

Get the mediatomb source:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep mediatomb
sudo apt-get source mediatomb
```

now edit debian/rules to enable javascript

```
sudo nano <mediatombfolder>/debian/rules
```

In the debian/rules file, search for MEDIATOMB_CONFIG_OPTIONS and change *--disable-libjs* to *--enable-libjs*.

You should also update the changelog file (in the same debian directory) and perhaps the "mediatomb.dsc" file to change the version.

**check and repack**

First:

```
cd <mediatombfolder>
sudo ./configure
```

This should confirm all necessary prerequisites are installed for compilation.

Finally:

```
sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -us -uc
```

If all goes well, you should see 3 new deb files in folder above .

Install them all:

```
sudo apt-get install libjs-prototype
sudo dpkg -i mediatomb*.deb
```

[based upon source](http://tobias-zimmer.blogspot.com/2011/07/howto-compile-mediatomb-with-javascript.html)

Comment: js script tested, it works as exepected.

Comment: Tha package links don't seem to exist any more