# Mediatomb segmentation fault on start watching video

Tags: segmentation-fault, mediatomb

I upgraded to 12.04 (from 10.04) today and it broke my mediatomb.  The issue I'm having is when I try to watch a video then media tomb suddenly crashes.  I added the `-D` flag to the options and ran the command from the command line.  No additional pertinent information was added to the log file in `/var/log/mediatomb.log`, but when I tried to play the video the response was `Segmentation Fault`.

I don't think it has to do with this issue [Mediatomb Javascript Support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60962/why-is-mediatomb-not-compiled-with-javascript-support) becuase I have turned off importing with Javascript (i keep my files in the order that I want them).

I don't think it's an ffmpeg issue becuase I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i "myfile" -target dvd -y "test"
```

and it started successfully encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to correct this exact same issue in Linux Mint 13 (based on Ubuntu 12.04) by doing the following. Have you tried this?

Move config and database files from the ~.mediatomb directory:

```
sudo mv /home/<user>/.mediatomb/config.xml /home/<user>/Desktop
sudo mv /home/<user>/.mediatomb/mediatomb.db /home/<user>/Desktop
sudo mv /home/<user>/.mediatomb/mediatomb.db-journal /home/<user>/Desktop
```

Then I started Mediatomb and let it recreate a default config and database file. I added a directory via the web interface and it started working again. So I shut it down and copied relevant info from my old config to the new one (I specify which directories to import/watch in the config file instead of the web interface - so I copied that over) and so far so good. There were a few differences between the new and old config files, so I assume there was a discrepancy in there somewhere. Here's my new (working) config file in case it will help you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config version="2" xmlns="http://mediatomb.cc/config/2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://mediatomb.cc/config/2 http://mediatomb.cc/config/2.xsd">
  <!--
     Read /usr/share/doc/mediatomb-common/README.gz section 6 for more
     information on creating and using config.xml configration files.
    -->
  <server>
    <ui enabled="yes" show-tooltips="yes">
      <accounts enabled="no" session-timeout="30">
        <account user="mediatomb" password="mediatomb"/>
      </accounts>
    </ui>
    <name>media@Mintop</name>
    <udn>uuid:c0bc3ac1-d8aa-45b4-9520-d503cc1a92e2</udn>
    <home>/home/mike/.mediatomb</home>
    <webroot>/usr/share/mediatomb/web</webroot>
    <storage>
      <sqlite3 enabled="yes">
        <database-file>mediatomb.db</database-file>
      </sqlite3>
      <mysql enabled="no">
        <host>localhost</host>
        <username>mediatomb</username>
        <database>mediatomb</database>
      </mysql>
    </storage>
    <protocolInfo extend="no"/><!-- For PS3 support change to "yes" -->
    <!--
       Uncomment the lines below to get rid of jerky avi playback on the
       DSM320 or to enable subtitles support on the DSM units
    -->
    <!--
    <custom-http-headers>
      <add header="X-User-Agent: redsonic"/>
    </custom-http-headers>

    <manufacturerURL>redsonic.com</manufacturerURL>
    <modelNumber>105</modelNumber>
    -->
    <!-- Uncomment the line below if you have a Telegent TG100 -->
    <!--
       <upnp-string-limit>101</upnp-string-limit>
    -->
    <extended-runtime-options>
      <ffmpegthumbnailer enabled="yes">
        <thumbnail-size>128</thumbnail-size>
        <seek-percentage>5</seek-percentage>
        <filmstrip-overlay>yes</filmstrip-overlay>
        <workaround-bugs>no</workaround-bugs>
        <image-quality>8</image-quality>
      </ffmpegthumbnailer>
      <mark-played-items enabled="yes" suppress-cds-updates="yes">
        <string mode="prepend">*</string>
        <mark>
          <content>video</content>
        </mark>
      </mark-played-items>
    </extended-runtime-options>
  </server>
  <import hidden-files="no">
   <filesystem-charset>UTF-8</filesystem-charset>
    <metadata-charset>UTF-8</metadata-charset>
    <autoscan use-inotify="yes">
      <directory location="/media/Gurt/1_TV" mode="inotify" recursive="yes" hidden-files="no"/>
      <directory location="/media/Gurt/2_Film" mode="inotify" recursive="yes" hidden-files="no"/>
      <directory location="/media/Gurt/7_Downloads" mode="inotify" recursive="yes" hidden-files="no"/>
      <directory location="/media/Gurt/4_Exercise" mode="inotify" recursive="yes" hidden-files="no"/>
      <directory location="/media/Gurt/3_Music" mode="inotify" recursive="yes" hidden-files="no"/>
    </autoscan>
    <scripting script-charset="UTF-8">
      <virtual-layout type="disabled"/>
    </scripting>
    <mappings>
      <extension-mimetype ignore-unknown="no">
        <map from="mp3" to="audio/mpeg"/>
        <map from="ogx" to="application/ogg"/>
        <map from="ogv" to="video/ogg"/>
        <map from="oga" to="audio/ogg"/>
        <map from="ogg" to="audio/ogg"/>
        <map from="ogm" to="video/ogg"/>
        <map from="asf" to="video/x-ms-asf"/>
        <map from="asx" to="video/x-ms-asf"/>
        <map from="wma" to="audio/x-ms-wma"/>
        <map from="wax" to="audio/x-ms-wax"/>
        <map from="wmv" to="video/x-ms-wmv"/>
        <map from="wvx" to="video/x-ms-wvx"/>
        <map from="wm" to="video/x-ms-wm"/>
        <map from="wmx" to="video/x-ms-wmx"/>
        <map from="m3u" to="audio/x-mpegurl"/>
        <map from="pls" to="audio/x-scpls"/>
        <map from="flv" to="video/x-flv"/>
        <map from="mkv" to="video/x-matroska"/>
        <map from="mka" to="audio/x-matroska"/>
        <!-- Uncomment the line below for PS3 divx support -->
        <!-- <map from="avi" to="video/divx"/> -->
        <!-- Uncomment the line below for D-Link DSM / ZyXEL DMA-1000 -->
        <!-- <map from="avi" to="video/avi"/> -->
      </extension-mimetype>
      <mimetype-upnpclass>
        <map from="audio/*" to="object.item.audioItem.musicTrack"/>
        <map from="video/*" to="object.item.videoItem"/>
        <map from="image/*" to="object.item.imageItem"/>
        <map from="application/ogg" to="object.item.audioItem.musicTrack"/>
      </mimetype-upnpclass>
      <mimetype-contenttype>
        <treat mimetype="audio/mpeg" as="mp3"/>
        <treat mimetype="application/ogg" as="ogg"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-flac" as="flac"/>
        <treat mimetype="image/jpeg" as="jpg"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-mpegurl" as="playlist"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-scpls" as="playlist"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-wav" as="pcm"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/L16" as="pcm"/>
        <treat mimetype="video/x-msvideo" as="avi"/>
        <treat mimetype="video/mp4" as="mp4"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/mp4" as="mp4"/>
        <treat mimetype="application/x-iso9660" as="dvd"/>
        <treat mimetype="application/x-iso9660-image" as="dvd"/>
        <treat mimetype="video/x-matroska" as="mkv"/>
        <treat mimetype="audio/x-matroska" as="mka"/>
      </mimetype-contenttype>
    </mappings>
    <online-content>
      <YouTube enabled="no" refresh="28800" update-at-start="no" purge-after="604800" racy-content="exclude" format="mp4" hd="no">
        <favorites user="mediatomb"/>
        <standardfeed feed="most_viewed" time-range="today"/>
        <playlists user="mediatomb"/>
        <uploads user="mediatomb"/>
        <standardfeed feed="recently_featured" time-range="today"/>
      </YouTube>
    </online-content>
  </import>
  <transcoding enabled="no">
    <mimetype-profile-mappings>
      <transcode mimetype="video/x-flv" using="vlcmpeg"/>
      <transcode mimetype="application/ogg" using="vlcmpeg"/>
      <transcode mimetype="application/ogg" using="oggflac2raw"/>
      <transcode mimetype="audio/x-flac" using="oggflac2raw"/>
    </mimetype-profile-mappings>
    <profiles>
      <profile name="oggflac2raw" enabled="no" type="external">
        <mimetype>audio/L16</mimetype>
        <accept-url>no</accept-url>
        <first-resource>yes</first-resource>
        <accept-ogg-theora>no</accept-ogg-theora>
        <agent command="ogg123" arguments="-d raw -o byteorder:big -f %out %in"/>
        <buffer size="1048576" chunk-size="131072" fill-size="262144"/>
      </profile>
      <profile name="vlcmpeg" enabled="no" type="external">
        <mimetype>video/mpeg</mimetype>
        <accept-url>yes</accept-url>
        <first-resource>yes</first-resource>
        <accept-ogg-theora>yes</accept-ogg-theora>
        <agent command="vlc" arguments="-I dummy %in --sout #transcode{venc=ffmpeg,vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,fps=25,aenc=ffmpeg,acodec=mpga,ab=192,samplerate=44100,channels=2}:standard{access=file,mux=ps,dst=%out} vlc:quit"/>
        <buffer size="14400000" chunk-size="512000" fill-size="120000"/>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
  </transcoding>
</config>
```